# Rails how to change settings in model dependent on action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to choise which height and width a youtube video should have dependent on action with an instant variable. But it does not work.

My controller:

```
class PublicController < ApplicationController
def index
@posts = Post.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(5)
@width = '600'
@height = '600'
end
end
```

My model:

```
def body_html

 auto_html self[:body_html] do
   html_escape
   image
   youtube(:width => @width, :height => @height)
   link :target => "_blank", :rel => "nofollow"
   simple_format
  end
  end
```

Comment: What about the code of the view? Do you get error messages?

Comment: no I dont get any error. But the width and the height of the video is not 600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume body_html is you'r model's method

you're setting instance variables @width and @height in context of controller, not model

try this:

```
class PublicController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(5)
    @posts.each do |post|
      post.width = '600'
      post.height = '600'
    end
  end
end
```

P.S.

your problem is actually wrong understanding of MVC pattern, your body_html method is way too presentational and it should be extracted into separate _post.html.erb template or whatever

that template can access all instance variables defined in controller so your original controller method can remain unchanged

P.P.S.

here are some quick code snippents:

in controller:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
  @width = @height = '600'
end
```

in index.html.erb

```
<%= render :collection => @posts %>
```

in _post.html.erb

```
...
<%= post_youtube(post, @width, @height) %>
...
```

Comment: I dont have any columns named width and height

Comment: then define getter and setter for width and height using attr_accessor :width, :height

Comment: I dont have any view helper named post_youtube. Auto_html automatic makes a youtube link embedded. And the settings is in the model.

Comment: i know you don't have it in your helper, you have to create it yourself. your model should not know about how and where is it displayed - it's something you do in your views

Comment: I don't see how the view helper should work with the model. http://rors.org/2010/08/15/auto_html.html

Comment: well you can include AutoHtml into your helper and do all same things

Comment: Can you show my how the application helper should look like ?

Comment: just copy paste your body_html method, make it accept post as argument and instead of self[:body_html] put post.body_html